# how to access php file on apache server by PHONEGAP based ecomerce mobile app?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, web-services, cordova

I don't have much experience with coding and m stuck with my project. PLEASE HELP!!

I am developing Buyers Guide app with Phonegap. I am using ebay api to fetch product info. Its php code is working on browser with apache server. But when i tried to load and run it on simulator, it didnt worked.
(this is d page which opens after clicking "Search product" hyperlink)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery-1.9.1.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $('#div1').load('http://localhost/MySample.php');
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="div1"><h2>Click to get information</h2></div>
<button>Get External Content</button>

</body>
</html>
```

How Can i access data from server then? Do i need to create web service?If yes then which approch should I use?or Ajax would work? i havnt used anything among these approches before and googling this is creating so much confusion. so plz suggest simpler one.

Thanking You in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

the call `$('#div1').load('http://localhost/MySample.php');` is not okay, because you should call another machine. `localhost` it the same machine- in your case it is phone.

Try to provide you server **IP address** where MySample.php script is placed